# Creating dashboard for a web site using python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to build a dashboard for a website. Could you please give me some suggestion. I want to use python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org).

Per their website:

> Flask is a microframework for Python based on Werkzeug, Jinja 2 and good intentions.

The documentation is really good and I've used it at work for several dashboard style projects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I have drawn up amending the resources I have around the internet.

```
This app creates a simple sidebar layout using inline style arguments and the
dbc.Nav component.

dcc.Location is used to track the current location, and a callback uses the
current location to render the appropriate page content.
Each page should have a different chart layout as its content.
The active prop of each NavLink is set automatically according to the current
pathname. To use this feature you must install dash-bootstrap-components >= 0.11.0.

For more details on building multi-page Dash applications, check out the Dash
documentation: https://dash.plot.ly/urls

import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output #for the callbacks


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY])

# the style arguments for the sidebar. We use position:fixed and a fixed width
SIDEBAR_STYLE = {
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "16rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    "background-color": "black",
}

# the styles for the main content position it to the right of the sidebar and
# add some padding.
CONTENT_STYLE = {
    "margin-left": "18rem",
    "margin-right": "2rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
}

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Sidebar", className="display-4"),
        html.Hr(),
        html.P(
            "A simple sidebar layout with navigation links", className="lead"
        ),
        dbc.Nav(
            [
                dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 1", href="/page-1", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 2", href="/page-2", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 3", href="/page-3", active="exact"),
            ],
            vertical=True,
            pills=True,
        ),
    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)

content = html.Div(id="page-content", style=CONTENT_STYLE)
header = html.H4(
    "Side Example.py", className="bg-primary text-white p-2 mb-2 text-center"
)

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Location(id="url"),sidebar,header,content])


@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),[Input("url", "pathname")])
     #Output("line-chart", "figure"),
    

def render_page_content(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for HOMEPAGE')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for PAGE1')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for PAGE2')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    # If the user tries to reach a different page, return a 404 message
    return dbc.Jumbotron(
        [
            html.H1("404: Not found", className="text-danger"),
            html.Hr(),
            html.P(f"The pathname {pathname} was not recognised..."),
        ]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8001)
```